# Decipher this three times, periodically

Tags: knowledge, cipher

After hanging around this site for a little while I finally decided to put together a cipher for my first puzzle. I hope you guys enjoy it.

> 721036710273114701098011166107721028210373114691156812168987211178111

Don't let the length of the code intimidate you, it expanded exponentially as it was encoded. Your result should be a 4 character code of a letter and 3 numbers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Answer is:

> **K573**

Solution method:

> The numbers are ascii codes without spaces:
> **72 103 67 102 73 114 70 109 80 111 66 107 72 102 82 103 73 114 69 115 68 121 68 98 72 111 78 111**
>  Converting them gives you
>  **HgCfIrFmPoBkHfRgIrEsDyDbHoNo**
>  These look like elements, with atomic numbers
>  **80 98 77 100 84 97 72 111 77 99 66 105 67 102**
>  Ascii again, to
>  **PbMdTaHoMcBiCf**
>  Elements again, to
>  **82 101 73 67 115 83 98**
>  Ascii again, to
>  **ReICsSb**
>  Elements again, to
>  **75 53 55 51**
>  Ascii again, to
>  **K573**

I have no idea what that result means though.

Comment: That's it! The puzzle was initially made for a couple friends of mine who are rhythm game players, and 573 is known as the "Konami Number." I realize I probably could have modified the puzzle to be something less obscure.